# Spinner.SetSelection(0) resets second Spinner in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, spinner

My issue is that I have 2 Spinners in Xamarin.Android that needs to reset each other depending on which one is selected. Say I select something from Spinner1, then Spinner2 has to be reset and vice-versa, with `Spinner.SetSelection(0)` so that they defaults back to the 0 item.

Here's the code which in theory should work, but doesn't. What happens is when either one of them has an ItemSelected, both of the Spinners gets their SetSelected function called and both are reset, even tho both Spinners have their own Adapter, with their own function/event to call.

What could be the issue?

Code:

```
public Spinner spinner1;
public Spinner spinner2;

public void Init() {
    List<string> items = new List<string>();

    //Populate dta into Items for Adapter
    foreach(Data d in datas)
    {
        items.Add(d.ToString());
    }

    var adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.spinner_item, items);
    adapter1.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.spinner_item);
    spinner1.Adapter = adapter;
    spinner1.ItemSelected += spinner1_ItemSelected;

    var adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.spinner_item, items);
    adapter2.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.spinner_item);
    spinner2.Adapter = adapter;
    spinner2.ItemSelected += spinner2_ItemSelected;
}


public void spinner1_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    string value = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
    //Use value ...

    //Reset spinner2
    spinner2.SetSelection(0);
}

public void spinner2_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    string value = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
    //Use value ...

    //Reset spinner1
    spinner1.SetSelection(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for a my issue. It's probably a hack solution, but since none could figure out how to solve this, this has to do for now:

```
public Spinner spinner1;
public Spinner spinner2;

public enum Spinners {
    Spinner1, Spinner2, None
}

public Types SelectedSpinner;
public bool IsChangingSpinner;

public void Init() {
    SelectedSpinner = Spinners.None;
    IsChangingSpinner = false;

    List<string> items = new List<string>();

    //Populate dta into Items for Adapter
    foreach(Data d in datas)
    {
        items.Add(d.ToString());
    }

    var adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.spinner_item, items);
    adapter1.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.spinner_item);
    spinner1.Adapter = adapter;
    spinner1.ItemSelected += spinner1_ItemSelected;

    var adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.spinner_item, items);
    adapter2.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.spinner_item);
    spinner2.Adapter = adapter;
    spinner2.ItemSelected += spinner2_ItemSelected;
}


public void spinner1_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
    if(IsChangingSpinner == false) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        string value = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
        //Use value ...

        //Reset spinner2
        IsChangingSpinner = true;
        spinner2.SetSelection(0);

        if(SelectedSpinner == Spinners.Spinner1) {
            IsChangingSpinner = false;
        }

        SelectedSpinner = Spinners.Spinner1;

    } else {
        IsChangingSpinner = false;
    }
}

public void spinner2_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
    if(IsChangingSpinner == false) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        string value = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
        //Use value ...

        //Reset spinner1
        IsChangingSpinner = true;
        spinner1.SetSelection(0);

        if(SelectedSpinner == Spinners.Spinner2) {
            IsChangingSpinner = false;
        }

        SelectedSpinner = Spinners.Spinner2;
    } else {
        IsChangingSpinner = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct as your issue says that, when you change the first spinner second spinner resets also you have written the reset code for spinner1 to reset it in the spinner two itemSelected. Whenever you change the spinner 1 content spinner two gets resetted to 0 th position. When spinner2 resetted to 0 th position at that time spinner2_ItemSelected will execute, so only both get reset.

Be clear with your need and change accordingly

```
public void spinner1_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    string value = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
    //Use value ...

    //Reset spinner2
    spinner2.SetSelection(0);
}

public void spinner2_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    string value = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
    //Use value ...

    //Reset spinner1
    //spinner1.SetSelection(0);
}
```

Comment: So how do you avoid that ItemSelected get's called when using SetSelection? Is that possible? Because that sounds like that is the root of the problem.

Comment: You have to maintain any one of the spinner as base, that should not be reset. For example, Keep spinner 1 as base, while changing spinner 1 reset the spinner two don't reset the spinner 1 while changing the spinner 2. I can be the followed way easier

Comment: Could you come with an code example in your answer?

Comment: Follow like above it will reset only the second spinner not the both

Comment: But only resetting the one, doesn't this mean that Spinner1 will actually never be reset when selecting Spinner2? That's what the code says.

Comment: What will be your exact scenario, kindly explain

Comment: The scenario is that when I select Spinner 1, Spinner 2 has to reset, and when I select Spinner 2, Spinner 1 has to reset. So the same as you said above, but vice-versa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155143/discussion-between-vass-tech-and-kevin-jensen-petersen).